# Trying to close a popup and reload its parent page

Tags: javascript, popup, window, reload

Here's my code:

```
function reloadParentAndClose() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
}
```

And here's the error I get:

> 32:132 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of null(…)

Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

It means that window.opener is null, and therefore trying to access the location property is invalid, since window.opener is null and therefore there is no such thing as window.opener.location